# collection_select within activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Activeadmin creates a nice dropdown menu for has_many & belongs_to associations. But since I needed to edit my form, these things where deleted.

In my original form, I used:

```
<%= f.label :artist_id %><br />
<%= collection_select(:work, :artist_id, Artist.all, :id, :name) %>
```

But this does not work in my admin/works.rb. The form i have created there is:

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Work do
  form do |f|
        f.inputs "Details" do
          f.input :title
          f.input :exhibition_id
          f.input :artist_id
          f.input :photo
        end

        f.buttons
      end
end
```

How can i create a similiar effect in my admin form?

Answer (score 0):

Activeadmin uses Formtastic and this is how i solved it:

```
f.input :artist, :as => :select, :multiple => false, :input_html => { :size => 1 }
```